# How can I find all implementations of interface in classpath in groovy project?

Tags: reflection, groovy

I'm implementing an interface and now I'd like to get all implementations of this interface in classpath. Is this possible or should I do something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [Reflections library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) for this sort of thing, ie; to find all classes in `org.codehaus.groovy` which implement the `Iterator` interface, you can do:

```
@Grab( 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5' )
@Grab( 'org.reflections:reflections:0.9.9-RC1' )
import org.reflections.*

new Reflections( 'org.codehaus.groovy' ).getSubTypesOf( Iterator ).each {
    println it.name
}
```

Which prints:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods$1
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SwingGroovyMethods$7
org.codehaus.groovy.util.ArrayIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ConcurrentReaderHashMap$KeyIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$9
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SqlGroovyMethods$ResultSetMetaDataIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SwingGroovyMethods$1
org.codehaus.groovy.util.ManagedLinkedList$Iter
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SwingGroovyMethods$3
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl$2
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SwingGroovyMethods$6
org.codehaus.groovy.ant.FileIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods$3
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$DropWhileIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$TakeIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$3
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SwingGroovyMethods$5
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SwingGroovyMethods$2
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ConcurrentReaderHashMap$HashIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ConcurrentReaderHashMap$ValueIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.XmlGroovyMethods$1
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.SwingGroovyMethods$4
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.IOGroovyMethods$2
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ReverseListIterator
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods$TakeWhileIterator
```